# Redirect to controller action in sub folder - Laravel 4

Tags: php, routes, laravel, laravel-4, controllers

I'm new to laravel. 
This might be very simple but i was unable to find an example or documentation.

I need to redirect the user to an action in a controller that is in a sub folder.

**Folder structure:**

```
**app**
---**controllers**
------**Admin**
---------AdminHomeController.php (extends AdminController)
------AdminController.php
------BaseController.php
---**models**
---**views**
------**admin**
---------dashboard.php
------login.php
```

**Routes.php**

```
Route::get('/login', function()
{
    return View::make('login');
});

Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('admin', 'AdminHomeController');

});

Route::post('/login', function()
{
    Auth::attempt( ['email' => Input::get('email'), 'password' =>       Input::get('password')] );

    **return Redirect::action('AdminHomeController@showAdminDashboard');**
});
```

After login i'm wanting to redirect to the action in AdminHomeController called "showAdminDashboard".
I know i could just load the view but i'm wanting to redirect.

My error is this - **Unknown action [AdminHomeController@showAdminDashboard]**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create new classes for things like controllers you'll need to dump your Composer autoload file again so that the classmap can be updated. If you open `composer.json` you should see a `classmap` key and the value will be an array of directories. One of the listed directories will be `app/controllers`.

Laravel doesn't know about your controller until your dump a new autoload. From a terminal simply run `composer dump-autoload`, it will take no longer then a couple of seconds.

Comment: Thanks for that but I had already run that -- 
       "autoload": {
  "classmap": [
   "app/commands",
   "app/controllers",
   "app/models",
   "app/database/migrations",
   "app/database/seeds",
   "app/tests/TestCase.php"
  ]
 },

Comment: I've you've already run it then open up `vendor/composer/autoload_classmap.php` and see if your controller is in the array. If it's not, you need to run `composer dump-autoload` again.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you namespace the controller, I think what you have to do is use an underscore to reference the controller in the route:

```
Route::group(array('before' => 'auth'), function()
{
    Route::resource('admin', 'Admin_AdminHomeController');

});
```

Then make sure to rename the AdminHomeController class:

```
class Admin_AdminHomeController extends AdminController {
```

Leave the file name the same "AdminHomeController.php" and leave it inside the "Admin" folder. After that, run `composer dump-autoload` again, and I think you'll be working.